# FlutterFlow not creating Firebase users collection on signup

Tags: firebase, flutterflow

I've recently started using FlutterFlow, on account creation... I have set it up so that it creates a users collection. The user gets created but not the collection. I can't even create a user document directly through the manage content section of Collections.

I've tried manually creating the users collection from Firebase directly but even that doesn't help. The collection can't be read by the app.

Here are the Firebase rules I'm using:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == document;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /chats/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /chat_messages/{document} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && 
                      request.resource.data.user == request.auth.uid &&
                      request.resource.data.chat != null &&
                      exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(request.resource.data.chat)) &&
                      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(request.resource.data.chat)).data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null &&
                    exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(resource.data.chat)) &&
                    get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(resource.data.chat)).data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;
      allow write: if false;
      allow delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also include your sample document structure in Firestore. I guess the rule should be like this: `if request.auth.uid == document.uid`

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue. I had to go into FF app, then go into the Firestore icon where you create collections. I had to create a users collection in FF. Once I did that, FF said "It looks like you're trying to create a user's collection". I confirmed that I am. I then I toggled on the user's collection switch to the on position. There still was no user collection in Firebase, so I ran a test session and created a new user and Firebase populated it. Its been working properly since.